# Error: Validation failed for one or more entities(C# .Net backend)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure

I know this error has been exhausted on StackOverflow, but I honestly believe I'm dealing with a different kind of error.

I'm working on a Xamarin.iOS app with azure mobile services, so an Azure .Net backend.

When the user creates a new account, I save a new account object in the database.

This happens in the backend, in a function that returns an `HttpResponseMessage`, returning a success or failure message.

While saving the new account details, I also generate a **salt** and **hash** the password. I save both the salt and the hashed password.

The error happens on `SaveChanges()`, but I noticed that the salt is null in the database.

```
[MobileAppController]
[RoutePrefix("api/register")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public class RegisterController : ApiController
{

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("newuser")]
    public HttpResponseMessage NewUser(RegistrationRequest request)
    {
        try
        {

            //...... code truncated for brevity

            myContext context = new myContext();
            DataObjects.Account account = context.Accounts.Where(a => a.Username == request.username).SingleOrDefault();

            if (account != null)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new
                {
                    message = "That username already exists",
                    error = true
                });

            }
            else
            {
                    byte[] salt = CustomLoginProviderUtils.generateSalt();

                    DataObjects.Account newAccount = new DataObjects.Account()
                    {
                        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                        Username = request.username,
                        Salt = salt,
                        CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow,
                        SaltedAndHashedPassword = CustomLoginProviderUtils.hash(request.password, salt)
                    };
                    context.Accounts.Add(newAccount);
                    context.SaveChanges();

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new
                {
                    message = "Account created successfully!",
                    error = false,
                    account = newAccount
                });
        }

            
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // Retrieve the error messages as a list of strings.
            //var errorMessages = ex.EntityValidationErrors.SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors).Select(x => x.ErrorMessage);

            //// Join the list to a single string.
            //var fullErrorMessage = string.Join(";", errorMessages);

            //// Combine the original exception message with the new one.
            //var exceptionMessage = string.Concat(ex.Message, "The validation errors are:", fullErrorMessage);

            // Throw a new DbEntityValidationException with the improved exception message.
            //throw new DbEntityValidationException(exceptionMessage, ex.EntityValidationErrors);

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new
            {
                message = "Failed!",
                error = true
            });            
        }
```

As you can see from the code above, after much research from here, I came across a solution to print out all the errors from the `DbEntityValidationException`.

I have 3 challenges:

1. I realized that the error doesn't throw an exception, and always returns an `HttpResponseMessage`

`{{message: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details, error: true}}`

This makes it harder for me to identify what columns exactly are failing.

I even tried overriding the `SaveChanges()` function in my `DbContext` class and implemented the above in the exception, but it never raises an exception. So again, I'm not sure what's failing.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
    {

        try
        {
            return base.SaveChanges();

        }catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
            // Retrieve the error messages as a list of strings.
            var errorMessages = ex.EntityValidationErrors.SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors).Select(x => x.ErrorMessage);

            // Join the list to a single string.
            var fullErrorMessage = string.Join(";", errorMessages);

            // Combine the original exception message with the new one.
            var exceptionMessage = string.Concat(ex.Message, "The validation errors are:", fullErrorMessage);

            // Throw a new DbEntityValidationException with the improved exception message.
            throw new DbEntityValidationException(exceptionMessage, ex.EntityValidationErrors);
        }
    }
```

I suspected the salt value was what was causing the error, but I have allowed a NULL value for the salt column, which is of `varbinary(Max)` data type in my database. So a null value shouldn't be a problem.

2.**Challenge number 2 is I have tested the salt generation on my client side, and I can see the values generated are not null.

So I'm not sure why it's not being saved to the database.**

```
**Generate Salt function**

 public static byte[] generateSalt()
    {
        RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] salt = new byte[256];
        rng.GetBytes(salt);
        //rng.GetNonZeroBytes(salt);
        return salt;
    }
```

**3. The final challenge is I'm not sure where the HttpResponseMessage is being returned from.**

The only place I set the error to true are when an existing account is found and in the exception on this NewUser function. I know it's not coming from the exception because, no matter how many times I change the `message` on the response, and the error property value, the result is always the same- The validation failed error message.

Kindly help me identify the cause of this error. Thanks.

**Edit**

**The Account class schema**

```
    public class Account : EntityData
     {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public byte[] Salt { get; set; }
        public byte[] SaltedAndHashedPassword { get; set; }

     }

[![Accounts Table Schema][1]][1]
```

Comment: Are you saying when you run the API locally you don't get the error? What does your Account entity model look like? Are you using Azure SQL? Are you running against the same database? If it is running against a different db have you compared the schemas?

Comment: benjrb, the validation error is returned as an HttpResponseMessage locally. So that's the error I get locally. I am also running against the same database. I am updating the question to reflect the schema of the Account class

Comment: What you're saying doesn't make sense. Your code is definitely throwing an exception. You will always get a response but in this case it will be a 500 Internal Server Error and the error message you are seeing. You need to log the exception so you can get more details about the error. If you are running the API locally then try debugging your code and put a breakpoint on SaveChanges, look inside the exception details for the validation errors.
Just out of interest, how did you create your database, was it code first? I suspect you can't combine varbinary(max) with byte[] in your entity model

Comment: I'm not running the API locally. So I have not been able to debug and step through that code. I'm not sure how to do that. I instead, like you can see in my code,I look for the errors in the exception and print that as the returned message. This hasn't worked so far. The message isn't affected by my changes(what I pass into it). I used code first to create the database. And I have another project in which the Accounts table, the salt and the registration is a replica of what I have here. The code works and the salt value is saved without any issues.